# How does 3 modulo 7 = 3?

Tags: modulo

I was wondering how modulo works. I know how it works when the bigger number comes first, but not the opposite. I know that `7 % 3 = 1` as 3 goes up to 7 2 times and the remaining is 1. However, when it's `3 % 7`. I have used the calculator it shows 3. Is this because 7 goes up to 3 zero times and the remaining is 3? Is that how it works?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 3 / 7 = 0, remainder 3

Comment: [Details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Any time the divisor is larger than the dividend, the result of the modulo operation equals the dividend.

Comment: Ok, what about 3^15 % 17. How is that 6? 3^15 = 14348907. 14348907 / 17 = 844053

Comment: @App - Because the divisor (17) is not larger than the dividend (14348907).

Comment: How come? It is larger?

Comment: @App - Sorry. Apparently I can't think today. I had my comment backwards.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get 6?

Comment: Because 17 goes in to 14348907 844053 times w/ a remainder of 6? I'm not sure what you're not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

7*x + y = 3, x and y are int, and x >= 0,

what y = ?

yes, y = 3.

Answer (score 1):

3 % 7 = 3 How?

**Well we know that modulo returns the remainder.**

`3 / 7 = 0.428` means the highest number that can be multiplied by 7 to get 3 or a value close to 3 is 0.

`0 times 7 = 0`

which leaves 3 as our remainder value **(0+3=3)** so 3 is our answer.

Answer (score 0):

3 MOD 7 = 0R3

This is so because 3/7 is >0 but <1

Answer (score 0):

Mod just means you take the remainder after performing the division. When you divide 3 by 7 you get 3= 0*7 + 3 which means that the remainder is 3.

Answer (score 0):

7/3 -> 3 goes into 7 2 times, and 7 - (3x2) = 1, so your modulus is 1

3/7 -> 7 goes into 3 zero times, and 3 - 0 = 3, so here your modulus is 3